# Adjective/phrase for a situation that requires fast and accurate decisions

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, paraphrasing

My sentence is *At the individual level, it seeks to provide an objective risk estimate for medical decision making in the **highly charged and emotional** environment of intensive care*

I want to rephrase the bolded parts so as to give an effect of the intensive care being a place where decisions needs to be made fast and accurately because there is so much to lose if something went wrong. I thought of `high stakes` but I find it a little informal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the word and phrase that come to mind (coincidentally or not) have a medical connotation.

[**Critical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2 a** : of, relating to, or being a turning point or specially important juncture · a *critical* phase : such as (1) : relating to or being the stage of a disease at which an abrupt change for better or worse may be expected; also : being or relating to an illness or condition involving danger of death · *critical* care · a patient listed in *critical* condition (2) : relating to or being a state in which or a measurement or point at which some quality, property, or phenomenon suffers a definite change · *critical* temperature
> **b** : indispensable, vital · a *critical* waterfowl habitat · a component *critical* to the operation of a machine
> **c** : being in or approaching a state of crisis ·a *critical* shortage · a *critical* situation
> **d** : crucial, decisive · a *critical* test

[**Life-and-death**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/life-and-death):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : involving or culminating in life or death : vitally important as if involving life or death

Answer (score 0):

[Exigent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exigent#Adjective)

> Urgent; needing immediate action.
>
> Demanding; needing great effort.

That said, I suppose the above doesn't necessarily clarify the stakes, although it does imply them. I suppose `emergency`, or `triage` might be better. "The triage environment of intensive care."

Comment: Hmmm I really like exigent but having gone through its usage in example sentences, I feel it'll imply an impulsive nature to my context. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

**crucial**    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crucial)

> a. Extremely significant or important: "Infancy ... is now understood
>   as a crucial building block of human personality" (Anne Roiphe). b.
>   Vital to the resolution of a crisis or the determination of an
>   outcome: a crucial moment in the political campaign.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest **[pressurised](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pressurized)**:

> 2 *British* (of a person or situation) under considerable psychological or social pressure.
>
> *‘their ability to perform in a very pressurized environment’*

<sup>oxford dictionaries</sup>

That definition only mentions "psychological or social" pressure, but I personally would also use it for time pressure and the pressure to mkae the right decision.